# Python: how to get element that contain square bracket in list (list in list)

Tags: python, string, list, square-bracket

I try to generate new list from 'list', for example

```
['I','want','[to,you]','go','to','[park,school]']
```

*Sorry all, I would like to update reference list into

```
['I','want','['to','you']','go','to','['park','school']']
```

Output that I want are

```
['I','want','to,','go','to','park']
['I','want','you,','go','to','park']
['I','want','to,','go','to','school']
['I','want','you,','go','to','school']
```

But I still can not locate element that contains '['.

I try coding like: `if any("abc" in s for s in some_list):`

You do have idea for this case?

Comment: Did you really think `if any("abc" in s for s in some_list)` would work? Can you please demonstrate a more sincere effort at solving this problem?

Comment: You might want to rework your list in a more structured way:

`['I','want', ['to', 'you'],'go','to', ['park', 'school']]`

In this way you can iterate through your items regardless if they are strings or lists.

Comment: @Adriano I think it would be best to keep all data types uniform, So each member should be a list

Comment: @Adriano, if I rewrite list follow your recommend, how to code it.
I try to search but I can not found because I do not know 'keyword' to search.

Answer (score 1):

Dont' really understand your code.
But
`'[to,you]'` is a string

Try

```
if str[0]=='[' and str[-1] == ']':
     strList = str[1,-1].split(,)
```

to get the inner list

Comment: Sorry @tt123456 to make you confuse.
I already update reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
import itertools
s = ['I','want','[to,you]','go','to','[park,school]']
new_s = [i if not i.startswith('[') and not i.endswith(']') else re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', i) for i in s]
lists = filter(lambda x:isinstance(x, list), new_s)
combos = [(a, b) for a, b in itertools.combinations([i for b in lists for i in b], 2) if a in lists[0] and b in lists[1]]
final_results = sorted([[next(i) if b.startswith('[') else b for b in s] for i in map(iter, combos)], key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

Output:

```
[['I', 'want', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'park'],
 ['I', 'want', 'you', 'go', 'to', 'park'], 
 ['I', 'want', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'school'], 
 ['I', 'want', 'you', 'go', 'to', 'school']]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way by using `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
lst_eval = [(i, j[1:-1].split(',')) if j.startswith('[') else j for i,j in enumerate(mylist)]
idx, lst = zip(*[l for l in lst_eval if isinstance(l, tuple)])
for p in product(*lst):
    for i, v in zip(idx, p):
        mylist[i] = v
    print (mylist)
```

Output:

```
['I', 'want', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'park']
['I', 'want', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'school']
['I', 'want', 'you', 'go', 'to', 'park']
['I', 'want', 'you', 'go', 'to', 'school']
```